# Creating a python proxy server

Tags: python, python-3.x, proxy

Good day everyone, I`m trying to create a proxy server on the python programming language.

I have found such a solution at http://voorloopnul.com/blog/a-python-proxy-in-less-than-100-lines-of-code/ though the problem is that the script was written in Python 2.7 version but I`m writing in Python 3.0 version.

After a rewrite of the script to serve my needed 3.0 version, it still does not work.

I`ll explain shortly what I`m trying to do, everything is shown at this picture:

There is user - web-site and the proxy server between them.

If suggested, that proxy server - is the regular computer with windows OS, on which this script is launched. The user knows the IP address of the proxy server, enters it in the setting of browser Firefox and moves to the web site myip.com on this web-sites displays the IP address of the server - that is the correct operation of this script, but neither my works. Maybe there is any ready-made solution to this problem?

Comment: Your question could be improved. Did you see there is an email address at the top of the code you linked? I suggest you to reach out to the original author.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do?
To me it isn't clear if you are trying to make a reverse proxy: all connections to _a single server_ must go through the proxy, or a forwards proxy: all connections from a client to _any server must go through the proxy

Comment: @Minion3665 all connections from a client to _any server must go through the proxy

Comment: @Apelsin2020 you could try using 2to3 to convert the program from python2 to python3. When I did the script appeared to work

Comment: @minion3665 If possible, show the code in the answer. But as I understand it, this code allows you to connect to the final single server, and not to all sites. Maybe I'm confusing something

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I made a server few years back using [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/creating-a-proxy-webserver-in-python-set-1/)

```
def __init__(self, config):
    # Shutdown on Ctrl+C
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, self.shutdown) 

    # Create a TCP socket
    self.serverSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    # Re-use the socket
    self.serverSocket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

    # bind the socket to a public host, and a port   
    self.serverSocket.bind((config['HOST_NAME'], config['BIND_PORT']))

    self.serverSocket.listen(10) # become a server socket
    self.__clients = {}

while True:

    # Establish the connection
    (clientSocket, client_address) = self.serverSocket.accept() 

    d = threading.Thread(name=self._getClientName(client_address), 
    target = self.proxy_thread, args=(clientSocket, client_address))
    d.setDaemon(True)
    d.start()

# get the request from browser
request = conn.recv(config['MAX_REQUEST_LEN']) 

# parse the first line
first_line = request.split('\n')[0]

# get url
url = first_line.split(' ')[1]


http_pos = url.find("://") # find pos of ://
if (http_pos==-1):
    temp = url
else:
    temp = url[(http_pos+3):] # get the rest of url

port_pos = temp.find(":") # find the port pos (if any)

# find end of web server
webserver_pos = temp.find("/")
if webserver_pos == -1:
    webserver_pos = len(temp)

webserver = ""
port = -1
if (port_pos==-1 or webserver_pos < port_pos): 

    # default port 
    port = 80 
    webserver = temp[:webserver_pos] 

else: # specific port 
    port = int((temp[(port_pos+1):])[:webserver_pos-port_pos-1])
    webserver = temp[:port_pos] 


s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
s.settimeout(config['CONNECTION_TIMEOUT'])
s.connect((webserver, port))
s.sendall(request)

while 1:
    # receive data from web server
    data = s.recv(config['MAX_REQUEST_LEN'])

    if (len(data) > 0):
        conn.send(data) # send to browser/client
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Brother can you tell me what is ``conn``? where it is used earlier?